# Android.Views.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class android.widget.ImageView

Tags: c#, android, xml, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am trying to found solution for this almost for a week. Can someone please help with this error? When I build it I get no errors. Exception is thrown of course when debugging.This is what I get ->

"Android.Views.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class android.widget.ImageView".

So it seems the problem is that the View can't be set (I don't know why) even though I used the same example as shown here -> https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/android/other_ux/animation/frame_animation/ with minor changes (my animation list is not in "Resources->Anim" folder but it's in "Resources->drawable" folder and I don't use animation start "OnFocus"). So first of all, here is my Main.axml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/animatedscreen1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/FirstScreenAnimated" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Second of all, here is my "FirstScreenAnimated.xml" where I have animation-list of images.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:oneshot="false">
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/BoyIntro01"
        android:duration="80"  />
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/BoyIntro02"
        android:duration="80"  />
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/BoyIntro03"
        android:duration="80"  />
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/BoyIntro04"
        android:duration="80" />
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/BoyIntro05"
        android:duration="80" />
</animation-list>
```

And last of all, here is my "FirstActivity.cs" where I am trying to start the animation after my SplashScreen:

```
using System;

using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;
using ListViewSwipeItem;
using System.Threading;
using Android.Graphics.Drawables;
using Android.Support.V7.App;

namespace LiveBookIntro
{
    [Activity (Label = "Step 1")]
    public class FirstActivity : Activity
    {
        GestureDetector _gestureDetector;
        GestureListener _gestureListener;

        public object NavigationPage { get; private set; }

        ImageView imageView;
        AnimationDrawable animation;

        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);

            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main); //This is the line where I get the exception! 
            imageView = FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.animatedscreen1);
            animation = (AnimationDrawable)imageView.Drawable;

            imageView.Clickable = true;
            imageView.Click += ImageView_Click;

            _gestureListener = new GestureListener();
            _gestureListener.LeftEvent += GestureLeft;
            _gestureListener.RightEvent += GestureRight;
            _gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(this, _gestureListener);

            void GestureLeft()
            {
                StartActivity(typeof(SecondActivity));
            }

            void GestureRight()
            {
                //nothing
            }

        }

        private void ImageView_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!animation.IsRunning)
            {
                animation.Start();
            }
            else
            {
                animation.Stop();
            }
        }

        public override bool DispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev)
        {
            _gestureDetector.OnTouchEvent(ev);
            return base.DispatchTouchEvent(ev);
        }
    }
}
```

As I mentioned, I tried solving it with google and by myself but I can't.. So any help would be great! If you need more information I will reply quickly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line

```
android:src="@drawable/FirstScreenAnimated" />
```

must be

```
android:src="@anim/FirstScreenAnimated"
```

Comment: Now I get the error " Resources\layout\Main.axml(2): error APT0000: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'src' with value '@anim/FirstScreenAnimated'). (TaskId:242)
1>Done executing task "Aapt". (TaskId:242) " and as I mentioned, "FirstScreenAnimated" is in drawable folder, not in "anim" folder.

Comment: Can you provide full stack trace of the error you get.

Comment: " >0xF in LiveBookIntro.FirstActivity.OnCreate at C:\Users\operater\Desktop\LiveBookIntro\FirstActivity.cs:29,13  " This is one line I only have in my Call Stack. Nothing else.

Comment: Check size of your drawables. A common issue is an out of memory exception. So basically verify that the pixel resolution in your drawables images are just the minimum necessary for your layout.

Comment: If I resize my drawables they will be to small to fit the screen. I tried this solution -> put my images in "drawable-hdpi" folder-> it works (but only for 4 or 5 pictures), and I have 37 of them. So I get the same error. What do you think how can I solve this problem?

Comment: If you have 37 images allocated memory to play your animation-list is 37 * imageWidth * imageHeight * 4 bytes. If you want to use this is needed to scale down your images to minimum acceptable size and also add android:largeHeap="true" to your <application> tag in manifest. My best suggestion is to try some other approach like making .mp4 file and playing this as video.

Comment: I'm very short on time to do that and do you think it would be possible to have mp4 video if I can't even use pictures that are like 50kB each - I doubt that mp4 video would have less. Is it possible to maybe delete my imageView where I use animation after I swipe to change activity? Or something similar to that?

Comment: File size in this case does not matter, only that loaded in memory does. Other approach is to try load gif. Android actually can decode and display animated GIFs. I'm not so sure is it possible in xamarin but you can try it. You can see this example for reference https://github.com/Miserlou/Android-SDK-Samples/blob/master/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/graphics/BitmapDecode.java#L103

Comment: I tried with GIF extension but it's not recomended for Xamarin. I think i will reduce the sizes of files and see what happens.

EDIT: Now it works, i just reduced the resolution of pictures and it works!! Thank you for your time though. :)